# get browser history by using javascript and print by php

Tags: javascript, php, browser, browser-history

I need to say

```
$userid ="xx Number";
$pageurl ="http://www.example.com/" . $userid  . ".php";
```

Check browser history >> if user visited this page before $pageurl >> echo "welcome back!"

How i can do that please ?

Comment: If you could do this, it would be a huge security hole.  You should use a cookie.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot read the browsing history from the user's device. This would be a huge privacy issue. I don't want you to know my browsing history.

You will need to find other ways to track users. A typical solution would be to use a cookie.